Книги и другие источники по языку ассемблера
В этом вопросе собирается литература по языку ассемблера
Формат:
Имя Фамилия
"Название книги целиком и полностью" - ГГГГ
Не добавляйте новые ответы редактируйте этот
Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям

Сайты:
Учебник по ассемблеру на английском - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/index.htm
Все о ассемблере FASM - https://fasmworld.ru/
Программирование на языке ассемблера в системе MSX-2 - https://sysadminmosaic.ru/msx/assembler_programming_guide-fakhrutdinov_bocharov/
Начало программирования на ассемблере -
https://natalia.appmat.ru/c&c++/assembler.html
Учебник по программированию на ассемблере - https://programm.ws/kat.php?id=7
Инструкции процессоров Intel -
https://av-assembler.ru/instructions/
Хороший учебник по MASM -
https://metanit.com/assembler/tutorial
Думаю здесь найдётся всё:
https://www.cyberforum.ru/low-level/thread2208389.html
Документации:
Документация masm на сайте Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/microsoft-macro-assembler-reference?view=msvc-170
Документации по NASM на английском -
https://www.nasm.us/docs.php
Документация по ассемблеру FASM -
https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual
Документация по GNU ассемблеру(GAS) - https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_node/as_toc.html
Мануал по ассемблеру для процессоров AMD - https://www.amd.com/content/dam/amd/en/documents/processor-tech-docs/programmer-references/40332.pdf
YouTube:
Хороший плейлист по использованию ассемблера вместе с С++ в Visual Studio-
https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlheCABZdy3P1OUheSoV4CeRvna5kleB-
Уроки по ассемблеру tasm-
https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBIoB20sXBuQvzFT3Pxp0mFKWMG7x5vea
Книги:
Ю.Магда - "Ассемблер для процессоров Intel Pentium" - 2006
О.Калашников - "Ассемблер - это просто. Учимся программировать" - 2011
С.Зубков - "Assembler. Для DOS, Windows и Unix" - 2017
В.Гаркушка - "Ассемблер в примерах и задачах" - 2022
Д.Куссвюрм - "ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНОЕ ПРОГРАММИРОВАНИЕ НА АССЕМБЛЕРЕ X64 С РАСШИРЕНИЯМИ AVX, AVX2 И AVX-512" - 2021

Почему все ссылки не прямые, а через google?

Что вы имеете ввиду

Ну это явно ссылки на конкретные сайты и документы, но все они начинаются с перехода в гугл. Я предполагаю, что вы из выдачи поисковика копировали. Так лучше не делать.

Спасибо, сейчас исправлю

И не исправили.

Извините третьего сайт не существует

Т.е. вы сделали запрос в гугл и сюда скопировали чаcть выдачи? Пардон, но ценность такого ответа невелика. Какой-то смысл был бы, если бы вы привели свой опыт по прочитанным книгам и ресурсам, которые вам были полезны - кратенько уровень, на кого рассчитано.

MBo, думаю вы скоро передумаете насчёт своего мнения

Видео почему-то в разделе документации. Плейлист по tasm (опустим, что tasm давно мертв) - лучше указать, что это по DOS.

Ссылка на киберфорум (да, я видел, что не вы добавили) - лучше вообще какой-то отдельный раздел добавить для ссылок на списки литературы

Да, конечно, раз ответ модифицируется и улучшается.

https://programm.ws/kat.php?id=7 - копия копии самоучителя неизвестного авторства, местами с битыми картинками. Лучше вообще убрать. "Ассемблер AMD форум" - ссылка на ветку форума, начавшуюся и закончившуюся в 2004 году, всего 14 сообщений. Зачем? Вы будете каждую подобную ветку на рандомном форуме добавлять?

"Cudasm - ассемблер для gpu NVIDIA" - я рекомендую на x86 платформе сфокусироваться, иначе этот набор ссылок разрастется до неприемлемого размера

insolor, я вас услышал. Но я сфокусирован на платформах x86-x64

@МатвейЖуковский GPU - это по определению не x86. Еще обратите внимание, что если какой-нибудь символ слева вплотную к ссылке - ссылка становится некликабельной.

Спасибо insolor
